# Conversion vs different comparison

Tags: php, variables, comparison

If I have a variable which is given a string that could also be a number, as so:

```
$a = "1";
```

If I want to check if it is indeed equal to 1, is there any functional difference between

```
if((int)$a == 1) {
    whatever();
}
```

and

```
if($a == "1") {
    whatever();
}
```

Here I am thinking about PHP, but answers about other languages will be welcome.

Comment: No, in PHP there is no functional difference. The first case is what PHP does behind the scenes in the second case.

Comment: Depends on where `$a` comes from. If user input, be careful, as if `$a = "1a"` then the first is true but the second is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = "1"; // $a is a string
$a = 1; // $a is an integer
```

1st one

```
if((int)$a == 1) {
 //int == int
    whatever();
}
```

2nd one

```
if($a == "1") {
   //string == string
    whatever();
}
```

But if you do

```
$a = "1"; // $a is a string

if($a == 1) {
   //string & int
   //here $a will be automatically cast into int by php
    whatever();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you need to convert and then compare while in the second you only compare values. In that sense the second solutions seems better as it avoids unnecessary operations. Also second version is safer as it is possible that `$a` can not be casted to int.

Comment: Isn't comparing strings harder than comparing numbers though? What if it's a longer number, like `$a = "34287"`?

Comment: Well converting to an integer will again involve iterating over the string **plus** some additional operations.

Answer (score 0):

since your question also asks about other languages you might be looking for more general info, in which case dont forget about triple equals.  which is really really equal to something.

```
$a = "1";
if ($a===1) {
  // never gonna happen
}
$b = 1;
if ($b === 1) {
  // yep you're a number and you're equal to 1
}
```